# careerfy Theme "Apply Job" buttom javascript:void(0): error?

Tags: wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

im using careerfy wp the for my website https://entekottayam.online , I tried apply job by creating an employee account, but while i click "Apply Job" button, there is nothing happen **"javascript:void(0)"** , i tried by cleaning cache with W3 Total Cache, noting worked ! anyone can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to inspect the source it would say that there are duplicated requests on http and https and your browser has blocked the popup from running.
Try to fix your Https or disable any plugins that force your site to run on https like "Really Simple SSL plugin"